Custom metadata behaves differently for standard and custom objects
When using a custom metadata type with Metadata Relationship fields, the actual values written to the database are different for standard and custom objects.
Consider a custom metadata type MySelector__mdt type with 2 fields:

Object_Selector__c of type Metadata Relationship(Entity Definition)
Field_Selector__c of type Metadata Relationship(Field Definition), controlled by Object_Selector__c

When creating records of this type, there's a dropdown in which we can choose any standard or custom object, and then another dropdown to select any field of that object.
However, when reading the values via SOQL, there is a big difference between standard and custom objects.
Given a SOQL query:
List<MySelector__mdt> records = [SELECT Object_Selector__c, Field_Selector__c FROM MySelector__mdt];
The results are as follows:

Opportunity standard object:

Object_Selector__c: Opportunity
Field_Selector__c: Opportunity.IsPrivate


SBQQ__Quote__c custom object:

Object_Selector__c: 01IQI000003BDil
Field_Selector__c: 01IQI000003BDil.00NQI000006Mc8L



That makes it difficult to know programatically which object and field is stored, and makes the whole thing practically useless.
I'm guessing that's because SBQQ__Quote__c is a custom object. I am seeing the same ID in URL when I'm editing the fields in Object Manager, for example:

/lightning/setup/ObjectManager/Account/view
/lightning/setup/ObjectManager/Opportunity/view
/lightning/setup/ObjectManager/01IQI000003BDil/Details/view (for SBQQ__Quote__c)

Can anyone shed some light on this behavior and point to the best way to programatically retrieve the actual object name (in my case, SBQQ__Quote__c)?

When you query metadata with relationship fields, the relation will contain the SObject/Field Id not the API name of said SObject/Field.
You can actually query more information about the SObject/Field as the relation is to a EntityDefinition and a FieldDefinition.
List<MySelector__mdt> records = [SELECT Object_Selector__r.QualifiedApiName, Field_Selector__r.QualifiedApiName FROM MySelector__mdt];
String sObjApiName = records[0].Object_Selector__r.QualifiedApiName;
String fieldApiName = records[0].Field_Selector__r.QualifiedApiName;

this will give you the results.
ps. not all definition fields are available using this relationship query.
Object references:
EntityDefinition:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm
FieldDefinition: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm

Wow, thanks, I see the actual names.
I was unaware that there's such a relationship available. When I look at the page for setting up custom metadata type, I see only the names of the fields (the __c suffix). How can I know there's a relationship object available? Is a relationship always available in case the field is a complex type?

For most relations there will be the possibility of expanding the query similarly to this to include parent information, there are just few exemptions.

You could try using schema class to dynamically resolve the API Names based on the IDs you are getting from your metadata.
something like this -
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> globDesc = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Schema.SObjectType objType = globDesc.get('SBQQ__Quote__c');
String objectName = objType.getDescribe().getName();

Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = objType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
String fieldName = fieldMap.get('your id here').getDescribe().getName();


I don't think I can use schema class, because I don't have SBQQ__Quote__c, I have 01IQI000003BDil and I need to somehow map it to SB__Quote__c.

try - String fieldName = fieldMap.get('01IQI000003BDil').getDescribe().getName();

The only thing I have is 01IQI000003BDil, representing the Quote object . Mapping it to the actual object name is the essence of my problem. Without it,  I can't even do globDesc.get('SBQQ__Quote__c') to get the objType you are referring to, because I only have an ID, not the object name.
The only place where I found that ID is in Workbench -> Metadata Types & Components -> choosing Custom Object -> Components -> SBQQ__Quote__c -> ID: 01IQI000003BDil2AG. Even here it's not the same, this ID has the 2AG prefix.
